# MySQL Обновление информации на странице выводимой из БД php

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

С помощью этого кода я вывожу информацию о текущей композиции играющей в настоящий момент (по факту запись сделанная последней в БД, перезапись в БД происходит в среднем 3-5 минут, но бывают миксы которые по хронометражу 30-90 мин) мне нужно сделать чтобы информация обновлялась вместе с перезаписью в БД (хочется обойтись без Iframe), скажем отледил код что переменная изменилась и выводил новое значение.

```html
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("x.xx.xxx.xx", "xxxx", "xxxxxx", "db", 3306); 
// Формируем запрос из таблицы с именем songs
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `songs` ORDER BY date_played DESC LIMIT 1";
$result = $mysqli->query($sql); 
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
{ 
$album_art = $row['album_art'];
echo "<img src = "albumart/".$album_art."">";
echo 'Artist: '.$row['artist']; 
echo 'Title: '.$row['title'];
echo 'Album: '.$row['album'];
echo 'Year: '.$row['year'];
} 
?>
```

Comment: Чтобы оставлять комментарии от своей учетной записи и редактировать собственные сообщения, очень рекомендую вам зарегистрироваться на сайте.

Answer (score 1):

Вот чтобы прямо с записью в базу - это сложно. Можно просто отслеживать состояние базы данных и менять значение на странице.

Самый простой способ - это действительно iframe - т.е. невидимый фрейм время от времени перезагружается. В нем PHP скриптом формируется некоторый JavaScript код, который обновляет данные на родительской странице.

Более сложный и более правильный вариант - это использовть AJAX запрос. Каждый временной интревал формируется запрос к PHP скрипту, который делает запрос в базу и возвращает данныео треке (в XML, JSON или обычным HTML), а уже JavaSCript получив эти данные обновляет содержимое блока на основной странице, где выводится информация о треке.

UPD:
По вопросу в комментарии:
То что генерится в iframe может в результате выглядеть следующим образом

```
<script language="JavaScript">
  document.getElementById("current_track").innerHTML = "Track: ... Artist";
</script>
```

Каким образом генерировть эту строку вам видней. Главное не забыть про случай когда в строке с данными могут оказаться кавычки.

Все это может быть в невидимом фрейме. Ну а на самой странице должен быть блок

```
<div id="current_track">...</div>
```

Куда собственно и будет делаться вывод.

Comment: На сайте радио Jazz fm именно так и сделано: раз в 2 секунды запрашивается текстовый файл, содержащий JSON с текущей композицией.

Comment: я видимо неправильно выразился, в базу ничего писать не нужно. а вот мысль с невидимым iframе'ом действительно рабочая об этом я не подумал. а как правильно отображать результат работы невидимиого айфрейма? не хочется морганий как обычно это делает iframe. или достаточно просто изменить переменные?

Comment: Сделал как вы предложили код который до вывода поселил в отдельный php файл, его обновляемым iframom вставил перед выводом переменных, но к сожалению результата нет, я так понимаю нужно и вывод обновлять? морганий iframa не избежать?

Comment: @Max дополнил ответ деталями

Comment: дорогой newman я в целом получил обновление засунув весь код целиком в php файл которой обновляемым iframom подгружаю на сайт. все работает и даже на удивление не моргает. но с div'ом как вы написали я получу полноценный инструмент для вывода в нужном мне стиле и в любом месте сайта, очень хочется сделать именно так. но я  не так силен что-бы с ходу понять как использовать ваш код.  может разжуете, если не затруднит

Comment: Спасибо огромное за небезучастность!!!! справился с задачей, наслаждаюсь результатом.